# How to hide this Social Media Icons

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this code i want the social media icon to be hidden on startup and show up when click on button. As per now the Social Media icons are visible and when click on button they hide but i want opposite. Thank You

```
<div id="content">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="share" checked>
  <label for="share" class="label entypo-export"></label>
  <div class="social">
    <ul>
      <li class="entypo-twitter"></li>
      <li class="entypo-facebook"></li>
      <li class="entypo-gplus"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=entypo);

/* entypo */
[class*="entypo-"]:before {
  font-family: 'entypo', sans-serif;
}

::selection {
background: transparent;
}

html {
  margin:0;
  padding:50px 0;
  background:#231733;
}

#content {
  text-align:center;

  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
  padding:120px 0 10px 0;

  width:200px;
  height:20px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]{display:none;}

.checkbox:checked + .label{
  background:#7B7484;
  color:#231733;
}

.checkbox:checked ~ .social {
  opacity:1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(-90px);
  -moz-transform:scale(1) translateY(-90px);
  -o-transform:scale(1) translateY(-90px);
  transform:scale(1) translateY(-90px);
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
  -moz-transition:.5s;
  -o-transition:.5s;
  transition:.5s;
}

.label {
  font-size:16px;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin:0;
  padding:5px 10px;

  border-radius:10%;
  color:#7B7484;
}

.social {
  transform-origin:50% 0%;

  -webkit-transform: scale(0) translateY(-190px);
  -moz-transform:scale(0) translateY(-190px);
  -o-transform:scale(0) translateY(-190px);
  transform:scale(0) translateY(-190px);

  opacity:0;
}
ul {
  position:relative;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
  color:#fff;
  height:46px;
  width:180px;
  background:#3B5998;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}

ul li {
  font-size:20px;

  cursor:pointer;
  width:60px;
  margin:0;
  padding:12px 0;
  text-align:center;
  float:left;
  display:block;
  height:22px;}

ul li:hover {color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);}

ul:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:35px auto;
  height:0;
  width:0;

  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;

    border-top: 20px solid #3B5998;
}

li[class*="twitter"] {background:#6CDFEA;padding:12px 0;}
li[class*="gplus"] {background:#E34429;padding:12px 0;}
```

Comment: please provide javascript code you are using..

Answer (score 7):

Remove `checked` attribute from the checkbox. It will work

Comment: If your question has been answered, accept the answer